# Spring boot web - Autowire bean into an XML defined bean is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am converting my existing Spring 3.1 based web application into Spring Boot 1.2.5. I initially upgraded my old application to Spring 4.1.7.

The old application has many xml bean configuration files imported using init parameter `contextConfigLocation` in the `web.xml`. In the new Spring boot application these xml are imported  using `@ImportResource` in the main class.

When I start my application, I could see that the xml based beans are created with autowired fields `null`. When I debug the bean creation part, it looks like the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is not yet added to the beanfactory. But xml contains `<context:annotation-config />`, which suppose to add the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. Also this post processor getting added right after my xml based beans are created.

Many of the bean dependencies are autowired bean in the xml defined bean.

sample xml config:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z"/>
<bean id="discoveredResourceClasses" factory-bean="resourceManager" factory-method="getResourceClasses">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>x.y.z.resources</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Factotry Bean class which is used to create 'discoveredResourceClasses' bean:

```
@Service
public class ResourceManager implements Serializable{
    @Autowired
    protected IExtensionManager extensionManager;

    public List<Class<? extends Resource>> getResourceClasses(String ... packageNames)
    {
        return extensionManager.getExtensions(packageName, includeEverything, Resource.class);
    }
}
```

Autowired bean:

```
@Service
public class ExtensionManager implements IExtensionManager {

    public <T> List<T> getExtensions(String packageName, Map<String, String> filter, Class<T> clazz) {
        //busoinesslogic .
    }

}
```

Spring boot class :

```
@ImportResource("classpath*:xad-config-all.xml")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder              application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
```

}

At the time of `resourceManager`  bean creation, the field `extensionManager` is coming as `null`. So the factory-method(getResourceClasses) throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Post your main class. Spring Boot should already register the processor for you so you could remove that line from your XML. Looks like you are doing something wrong in your main class. Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please expand your question.

Comment: Post the class where you're calling that method.

Comment: Updated  my question with more information.

Comment: First `<context:component-scan />` already implies `<context:annotation-driven />`. Second Spring Boot uses an application context that has annotations enabled by default. One thing to try is remove theo `<context:annotation-config `> and the `<component-scan` elements. Move the `@ImportResource` after the `@SpringBootApplication` and move the `Application` class to the most upper level package you can use (not the root but somewhere in, `com.company.app` so that it can automatically scan all the `@Compoment` based beans. Then try again.

Comment: SInce I have to  scan specific packages from the jar, I have to use <component-scan elements.

Comment: @m-deinum
 I have tried following changes in   springboot class. But result is same
 
 
    Configuration
    EnableAutoConfiguration
    ImportResource("classpath*:xad-config-all.xml")
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { }  

 
 The xml based beans are getting created before the AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(beanFactory); method call. So autowiring is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide path to the xml configuration file at the beggining, when Spring didn't started building application context. The @ImportResource annotation are processed in the middle of this process, after many of PostProcessors have been registered.

You need to provide a path to the xml configuration using SpringApplicationBuilder.sources method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources("classpath:/WEB-INF/context/payables-profile.xml", Application.class);
}
```